# Get and use the data sent by autobahn wamp v1 server to client(Html)

Tags: python, python-2.7, autobahn

I have created a web socket using Web Application Messaging Protocol(WAMP v1) in python and I am connecting a client html application with it. The connection is successful and the data is sent successfully from client to server as well as it is getting sent from server to client also.

The problem I am facing is the that I cannot find a way to access the data sent from server to client using the sendMessage method or dispatch method.

My requirement is that i only want to access the data sent by the two above mentioned methods and use it for further processing.

Please reply as early as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`WebSocketProtocol.sendMessage` [in AutobahnPython](http://autobahn.ws/python) is part of the *WebSocket* API, not the *WAMP* API.

When using WAMP, `sendMessage` (and the corresponding `onMessage`) must not be used (it is used internally in the WAMP implementation already).

Instead, with WAMP, application data is transferred in RPC arguments/results and PubSub event payload.

Comment: Ok.. But is there any way that I can get the data on client side?

Comment: Sure. As a WAMP call result / event payload. See e.g. the AutobahnJS documentation.